# How to convert CAShapeLayer coordinates to CIRectangleFeature for manual crop

Tags: ios, crop, core-image, cashapelayer

I am dealing with manual image crop functionality. For this am drawing CAShapeLayer with four coordinates called topLeft, topRight, bottomRight and bottomLeft. User can pan the points and select the crop area.
I am stuck at converting these points to Core image coordinates and further cropping with CIPerspectiveTransform.

[image]

Comment: i think you try to crop image as shaplayer ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.
I am using shape layer for user's visualisation. What i intended to do is get this four points of shape formed by user and crop the image accordingly w.r.t. these points.
I am facing issues while converting these UIKit poins to CoreImage points.

Comment: provide you shape layer initialisation

Comment: var cropRectOverlay = CAShapeLayer()
cropRectOverlay.fillColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(25 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(17 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(100 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(0.3)).cgColor
cropRectOverlay.lineWidth = 3.0
cropRectOverlay.strokeColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(25 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(17 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(100 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0)).cgColor

Comment: Adding four buttons for topLeft, right, bottomLeft and right


topLeftButton.center = CGPoint(x: cropImageView.bounds.origin.x + 50, y: cropImageView.bounds.origin.y + 50)
bottomRightButton.center = CGPoint(x: cropImageView.bounds.size.width - 50, y: cropImageView.bounds.size.height - 50)
topRightButton.center = CGPoint(x: cropImageView.bounds.size.width - 50, y: cropImageView.bounds.origin.y + 50)
bottomLeftButton.center = CGPoint(x: cropImageView.bounds.origin.x + 50, y: cropImageView.bounds.size.height - 5)

Comment: cropingImageView.addSubview(topLeftButton)
cropingImageView.addSubview(topRightButton)
cropingImageView.addSubview(bottomLeftButton)
cropingImageView.addSubview(bottomRightButton)
cropImageView.layer.addSublayer(cropRectOverlay)

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to paste whole code this is how i have did it.

Comment: Okay i will post my answer check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set image to imageView And masking imageView with shape layer.

```
self.imageView = img
imageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer // set here your shape layer
```

Now your imageView have crop image.

Get image from current context as follow

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, 0);
imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// check cropping image
let resultImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
resultImageView.image = image
self.view.addSubview(resultImageView)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked really well. 
These are screenshot and resultant image:
file:///Users/Swapnil/Desktop/IMG_2082.PNG
file:///Users/Swapnil/Desktop/IMG_2083.JPG

I will need little more help from you.

Comment: @SwapnilDhapte i can't show your result. how can i help you?

Comment: Is there any way I can save image with only rendered part. Not with white background.
As i want to apply CIPerspectiveTransform on it.

Comment: set your image background color clear and try to save

Comment: Was unable to post image here hence have self answered the question :(

Comment: My aim here is the receipts scanning for OCR. I am clicking images through my app and need to crop out the receipt and apply CIPerspectiveTransform for better OCR.

Comment: let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
Here check your image with another image view. your image as you expected

Comment: Sorry, this time I did't get you.
But is it: CurrentContext is with the image view am using hence the resultant image is having that extra background?

Comment: i am updating my answer check it.

Comment: Earlier I was working with: "CIPerspectiveTransform - withInputParameters". 
but was not able to handle core image coordinate space with UIkit's space.

Comment: Can you please check my updated answer having link named "resultant screenshot".

this what m getting on app which is perfectly suited for my needs.
but when I go on and save this image to device it's been showed with link "resultant image"

Comment: check my answer and let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

Comment: don't use image view image

Comment: Yes, I got this point. I'm saving rendered image directly. Not the imageView's image.

Comment: As i save this rendered image to device gallery. I adds the white background to rendered part as the current context size is of original image.
For further processing is there any way not to have this white background.

Please help me out if yes or till this far your answer has worked great fro me.

Comment: i am not sure but try to save png image to gallary

Comment: Ok, sure. Thank you so much for your help.